# Installing PIL on MAC OS X LION 10.7.2 with PIP INSTALLER

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, llvm, pip

I am trying to install PIL using PIP installer, and I'm getting this:

```
llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_imaging.o

unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Any clues what the problem might be ?

I have Mac OS X Lion and LLVM is installed in the XCODE Developer tools...  What can be wrong ?

Comment: Are you very, very, very sure that XCode is installed? This really looks like you actually haven't.

Comment: It's weird. I ran the XCODE Installer, but before i ran it, the file already showed up in the developer. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have actually run the Xcode installer (usually found in `/Applications`)?  Downloading it from the Mac App Store doesn't automatically run the installer.

Answer (score 9):

i got the same error.
but additionally need to install the "commandline tools" under settings [image]

edit:
just a few keywords for google, if someone is looking for this! 
easy_install pip gcc not found mac osx xcode
may be a moderator add this keywords to the question

Comment: Your AppleID needs to be registered as an apple developer (free) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed XCode. Try installing a PIL from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager